HTTP interface in library with POJOs declared in project
At my company we have many projects which have to talk to the same REST endpoint. The response however is a very large JSON and in each project I only want to declare those fields which are need for the program. Currently we have declared the clients in each project like this:
public interface BookClient {
  @GetExchange("/api/v1/books")
  List<Book> getBooks();

  // many more methods and interface like this
}

I would like to move these clients to a shared library, however I want the POJOs to stay in the project itself. I thought I could use generics to achieve this:
@GetExchange("/api/v1/books")
<T> List<T> getBooks();

This compiles fine but when I call the method spring returns a Map<String, String> with the JSON key and value pairs. This is totally understandable when I think about it: Of course the library does not know how to instantiate the POJO because it isn't available in its classpath.
What other options do I have here? Is there maybe a way to return something else from the API call and do the actual mapping to the POJO in the project itself?

Have you tried to extend the objects for a central object? This way you can keep all the library objects in the library and extend them to the respective end points accordingly.

Have you ever tried that parse your entity with the return value  jsonString ?

Receive return value as string
public interface BookClient {
    @GetExchange("/api/v1/books")
    String getBooksRaw(); // Returns raw JSON as String
}

and use  Jackson or ObjectMapper for post-processing  in every independent moudle.
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Book> books = objectMapper.readValue(bookClient.getBooksRaw(), new TypeReference<List<Book>>() {});


Step 0: let the REST API server send all the data that it needs. No Change needed
Step 1: Create your own POJO class in the client application or in the shared module and use the JSONIgnoreProperties annotation at class level
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyPojo   
 {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private short publicationYear;

}

Step 2: Consider the response from the rest endpoint as a string
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url,` String.class);

Step 2: Convert the string to your respective POJO class using jackson object mapper
  public  MyPojo jsonStringToPojo()  {
        String jsonString = "{\"title\":\"stack overflow stories\", \"author\":\"Vamsi krishna Tandlam\", \"publicationYear\":2024, \"publishedBy\":\"Arihant Publications\",\"additonal field2\":\"test\"}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyPojo myPojo= mapper.readValue(jsonString, MyPojo.class);
        
        System.out.println(myPojo.getTitle());
        System.out.println(myPojo.getAuthor());
        System.out.println(myPojo.getPublicationYear());
        return myPojo;
    }


Well, we could have an academic discussion on how to get this implemented. Nevertheless it's a hack. Reading data from a persistence layer, sending around large JSONs and then only use some fragments of it on the client side is a bad design and will end up in poor performance.
Your problem is this single endpoint that should have been multiple. If there is any chance to split this endpoint (e.g. serving ThinBooks, CookBooks, PictureBooks, ...), then this is the way to go. If this is out of reach, then please don't make things worse by creating a shared library.

Here is an idea. Let the endpoimt return a map and not a pojo. Each client that sends the request can specify (in the header or any other way) what info it needs and your end-point will build client specific reply. You receive it as map and convert it to client specific POJO on the client side (or consume it as map)

Could possibly use JsonView to simplify the server side here. Client can simply specify a View name: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-methods/jackson.html

Ultimately, you probably want the POJOs to live with the interfaces, because that's what they return. Even if type inference could figure it out, it's difficult for someone reading the code to reason about it.
But answering your question as-written... I'd probably include a base POJO along with the interfaces, change your generic to something extending that POJO, and have a blank class extending that base in your individual projects.
